# Memory reduction in redis

Tags: json, redis

I am storing key value pairs of the form `didsha1_37c74c87d93aa45ec0d2fd88d0739e7c06ca8420 -> "{\"ck\":\"KKK_51da1f310498c\"}"`
But the memory occupied in cache is double the expected. Pointers seem to be occupying much space.
Can you please suggest  memory optimization tricks for 50M such entries. Mostly there is no other key apart from "ck" in the json value.

Answer (score 2):

You should read http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization . It recommend using Redis hashes and probably you could split at the first four or five digits of your SHA1 hashes. So, instead of `SET didsha1_37c74c87d... value` you'd run `HSET didsha1_37c7 4c87d... value`. Experiment a little what gives you best speed / memory.